# Аналог UploadString на питоне

Tags: php, c#, python

Нужен аналог `uploadString` для питона, что бы данные поступали в `php://input`

Пример кода на шарпе

```
WebClient cl = new WebClient();
cl.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
Console.WriteLine(cl.UploadString("http://url.com", "input values"));
Console.ReadKey();
```

Пример обработчика на php

```
<?php

echo file_get_contents('php://input');

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы послать текст, закодированный в utf-8 кодировке, используя http POST:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from urllib.request import urlopen

print(urlopen("http://url.com", "input values".encode()).read().decode())
```